# Why can't validate unchecked value on checkbox item in my html table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i got a html table like this one on my page, witch include a checkbox item, the problem i got is that i want to validate if the checkbox item is checked or not (i mean true or false), but when i validate the value in each record i can't identify when it is unchecked. All i can validate is a checked value, but the else is not working.

here is a snipset of my table where i define the checkbox filed :

```
   <tr>
   <td><input type="checkbox" name="f_mark" value="true"></td>
   </tr>
```

and here i got a function where i wan t to validate if it is check or not:

```
> function hiderow() {
>        $("input[name=f_mark]:checked").each(
>             function () {
>                 var marc = $(this).val();
>                 if (marc == 'true') {
>                   alert('checked value');
>                 } else {
>                   alert('unchecked value');
>                 }
>             }
>         );    }
```

why i can't identify the unchecked row ???
is something in definition or validation ??

thanks in advance.
Sib

Comment: You're explicitly selecting *only* the `:checked` checkboxes (`$("input[name=f_mark]:checked")`); which rules out the possibility that any of them could be unchecked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of you choose only **checked** checkboxes by using this rule:

```
$("input[name=f_mark]:checked")
```

The correct way in your case is:

```
$('input[name=f_mark]').each(function () {
   if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
     alert('checked');
   } else {
     alert('unchecked');
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function hiderow() {
    $("input[name=f_mark]").each(function() {
        if ($(this)[0].checked) {
            alert('checked value');
        } else {
            alert('unchecked value');
        }
    });
}
```

Notes:

- remove `:checked` from selector
- `.val()` returns the checkbox `value` attribute, not the `checked` attribute
- replace `.val() == 'true'` with `[0].checked` in the if statement